# Задача по информатике на питоне

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

Я недавно начал учить пайтон, и на информатике нам дали задачу, но у меня постоянно вылезает ошибка, либо выводится не то что мне нужно.
Вот сама задача: вводятся целые числа до первого числа, которое меньше двух. Определить, сколько простых чисел было введено. Если я ввожу список, то он сразу выдает count = 0 и условие заканчивается. Как заставить в списке проверить каждый элемент, и при этом заставить счётчик работать?
Вот код

```
spisok = [input().split()]
for i in spisok:
    if i == 2:
        break
    else:
        if  i == 1:
            count += 1
    print(count)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> spisok = [input().split()]
> ```

```
spisok = map(int, input().split())
```

> ```
> if  i == 1:
> ```

```
if all(i % q for q in range(2, int(q**.5)+2)):
```

Comment: `input().split()` получится списков строк, а не чисел

Comment: @Danis, исправил.

Answer (score 1):

Вам учитель вообще ничего не объяснял что ли?

```
count = 0

while True:
    # получить от пользователя целое число
    number = int(input())
    
    # если число меньше 2 - прервать цикл
    if number < 2:
        break

    # проверить число на простоту и если число простое - увеличить счетчик
    if is_prime(number):
        count += 1

# вывести результат
print(f"простых чисел: {count}")
```

Ну а написать функцию проверки числа на простоту `is_prime()`, я думаю, не составит для вас труда